# What is meant by the statement "Local bypass capacitors are needed to control EMC coupling with heat sink"?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, emc, heatsink, emi-filtering

During a talk, not sure what the speaker meant by the statement " **We need to add local bypass caps  to control EMC coupling with heat sink**"
*He was referring to the MOSFETs in synchronous buck converter ( vertically mounted with heat sink) .* (Picture for representation purpose only)

[image]

[image: Picture for representation purpose only]

Drain (Tab) is connected to heat sink (through insulating plate) and heat sink is at GND potential . Depending on the MOSFET , Drain can be  at fixed  potential or fluctuating. There comes a parasitic capacitance between Drain and heat sink- which can cause a noise current through it. - I figured out till here.

**How does it cause EMI issue? Why should I add bypass capacitors - across which 2 points?**

Comment: High frequencies traveling in big loops cause EMI. Decoupling gives it an lower impedance path to flow that is a smaller loop.

Answer (score 5):

Parasitic capacitance and Cext added only shown for clarity.  The capacitor will also have parasitic inductance to gnd ~ < 10 nH/cm. The heatsink could also be 0V DC grounded but the shunt insulation capacitance might be an issue for crosstalk to the gates and may require further investigation.  (Dead-time and noise)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdY0IO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The point of the heatsink capacitor is to make the shortest loop area for circulating impulse currents to attenuate the E field antenna effects without significantly affecting the drain current by attenuation C ratio and ESR ratio.

Physically, the cap ought to be closer to the heatsink middle than the end of the heatsink.

I have not seen this done but I imagine a special layout is required.

Perhaps more important is the V+ to 0V or V- **decoupling capacitor loop area** and low ESR to reduce parastic inductance of the output switched currents high  dI/dt and dV/dt.

Comment: Can you please explain why separate grounds are being marked  in above diagram?

Comment: That was logical to show the voltage was not the exact same 0V due to parasitic I*Z=V changes(f) , sorry not very explicit

Comment: Just to double confirm- C1 is the bypass cap and it should ideally be at the point closest to parasitic capacitance and buck converter ground.

Comment: yes and the radiated noise couples between the thermal pads which if not used are connected to both drains for low Rja and then is live DC with more parasitic capacitance, which I have seen on 3ph 100W 70V BLDC 3500 cfm fans with ACDC built-in